# Exchange 2013: Unable to install Exchange on domain for the 2nd time

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2013

I'm trying to set up Exchange 2013.

There are two errors - not sure which one is fatal (perhaps both)

Eror 1:
Setup encountered a problem while validating the state of Active Directory: The Active Directory organization configuration version (15870) is higher than Setup's version(15844). Therefore, PrepareAD can't be executed.  See the Exchange setup log for more information on this error.

Error 2:
Global updates need to be made to Active Directory, and this user account isn't a member of the 'Enterprise Admins' group

The 2nd error surprises me because I've logged in with an account that has access to pretty much everything. I tried a second account, same result. Perhaps it has something to do with the process running as administrator.

Additional info: this is the 2nd time I have set up an Exchange 2013 server on the domain. This is probably why we have the version issue. I scrubbed the first server because it corrupted.

I have tried:

1. Installing from the dvd
2. Setup /PrepareAD /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms (on both the Exchange machine and the domain controller)
3. Deleting all the Exch containers in active directory (but not deleted entries from the schema)

Anyone help?

Comment: It really sounds like the help you need would be having someone with Exchange expertise set it up for you.  Exchange integrates pretty tightly with Active Directory, so "scrubbing" an Exchange server and deleting containers from Active Directory is actually a pretty good way to mess up Active Directory, and a totally ineffective way to actually uninstall Exchange. Additionally, the proper way to find out if a user is an Enterprise Administrator... is to actually check if the user is a member of the Enterprise Administrators group, not to try a couple of accounts and wonder about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rogerl

1. You need to open the Exchange error log located usually c:\Exhcangesetuplog (or similar directory), view the last section of the log, it should provide you with some information. Since you stated that you have ran the install already in the past, you either didn't remove/uninstall it properly or your AD DCs are out of sync, which is quite a big problem.
   In order to perform clean up of the AD, you can remove the Exchange manually, following this article:
   http://blog.dargel.at/2012/11/20/complete-remove-exchange-2013-using-adsiedit/

Basically, remove the "Microsoft Exchange" object.

I must warn you, those actions are very drastic and require adequate amount of knowledge in the area, I suggest you get help of the professional Exchange admin.

2. The account you're running setup with is not a member of "Enterprise Admins" AND "Schema Admins".

Answer (score 2):

> because I've logged in with an account that has access to pretty much everything.

You're not being very precise here. Go into ADUC and confirm if this account is a member of Enterprise Admins. This isn't rocket science, it's spelled out quite explicitly in the documentation and in this error you're getting.

But that's if you were having a problem with a clean AD. It sounds like you may have also trashed your AD in some way, it may be recoverable and it may not be. If this is production, I'd spend the few bucks and open a PSS ticket.

If it's not production, make a clean new lab, and read the "Help" link at the top of the page before posting again.

Answer (score 2):

> Setup encountered a problem while validating the state of Active Directory: The Active Directory organization configuration version (15870) is higher than Setup's version(15844).

You're using install media that's older than the previous time you installed.  That won't work, switch back to the newer media.

> Global updates need to be made to Active Directory, and this user
>   account isn't a member of the 'Enterprise Admins' group
>
> The 2nd error surprises me because I've logged in with an account that
>   has access to pretty much everything.

An account can have access to "pretty much everything" and still not be a member of the Enterprise Admins group. Verify that the user is in *that specific group*.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who responded.

The problem was that I was attempting to install using my original media and various updates had already changed the Active Directory organization configuration version. After downloading the latest cup (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45221) both the above errors were sorted.

To the folk that warned me about playing around with AD you were quite correct - it seems I broke quite a lot. I then had this problem:

"The well-known object entry 
B:32:C67FDE2E8339674490FBAFDCA3DFDC95:CN=Discovery Management\0ADEL:1a8b7727-3e6f-411a-9dc3-eb9bd4d7c0ad,CN=Deleted Objects,DC=xxx,DC=com
on the otherWellKnownObjects attribute in the container object 
CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=xxx,DC=com points to an invalid DN or a deleted object.
Remove the entry, and then rerun the task."

I had to use the info at this site to help me fix it:
https://support.software.dell.com/appassure/kb/132118

The site posted by Vick Vega was useful. I cleared everthing out correctly and started from scratch and now it seems ok

Comment: So, rather than marking someone else's correct answer as the accepted answer, you repeated their suggestions and marked your own answer as the answer. You may want to read up on the contents of the "help" link to learn how this site is intended to work.

Comment: To be fair to Vick Vega I have marked his answer as correct (as per suggestion by main) as it provided part of the solution.

Comment: @mfinni
With all due respect, I can easily give up any "received" points to any individual that more worthwhile.
Quite often, I'm seeing communications, down-votes, etc based on preference of that or other individual in regards to the questions asked.
I think some forgetting the true goal of the site is to provide help, regardless of the level and depth of the question.
This is my personal take on it and I'll address all the questions on which I can help with equal amount of respect and due diligence.

I always keep in mind the time when I was exactly in the same spot. Just staring ...

Comment: I wasn't complaining that I hadn't been picked as the answer - I was complaining that @RogerI had picked his own answer, after using the information he had been given. Shane and Vick both had good pieces of the answer and either should have been marked.